# How to convert space delimited multiple lines string to json with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a web application where users can copy their excel data (multiple rows with 2 columns) onto a website's text area.  When clicking submit button on the same page, it will covert the excel data to JSON, displays the JSON in a different text area on the same web page.

I already got a HTML page going, just not certain how to write the convert code.  (Code below)

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset = "utf-8" />

      <title>Convert</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Convert Table Data (2 Columns) To JSON</h1>

      <button onclick="convert()">Convert to JSON</button>
      <br><br>

      <textarea id="inputText" rows="50" cols="100"></textarea>
      <textarea id="outputText" rows="50" cols="100" readonly></textarea>

      <script>
        var textarea = document.getElementById("inputText");
        var textarea2 = document.getElementById("outputText");
        function convert() {
           // textarea2.value = textarea.value.convertToJSON......
        }
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is what the excel data will look like when copied and pasted into a text area:

```
Amy apples
Betty oranges
Cathy watermelon
Daisy bananas
Edward pears
Fiona grapes
```

Expected results to be displayed on different text area after submit:

```
{
 "Amy" : "apples",
 "Betty" : "oranges",
 "Cathy" : "watermelon",
 "Daisy" : "bananas",
 "Edward" : "pears",
 "Fiona" : "grapes"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trim the string, then split it by `\n` to an array of strings, map the array and split the items by space. Now you can convert the array of arrays to an object with `Object.fromEntries()`:

```js
const str = `Amy apples
Betty oranges
Cathy watermelon
Daisy bananas
Edward pears
Fiona grapes`

const result = Object.fromEntries(str.trim().split('\n').map(s => s.split(' ')))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Nice approach! Why did you use trim? Won't the string have no spaces then ?

Comment: It won't have redundant spaces before or after the text, that will create `"": ""` properties. The spaces inside would be preserved.

Comment: Thank you so much, I just tried this solution, and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

How about splitting the string and then forEach over the array while putting the keys + values in an object?

```js
// your textarea
let textarea = document.querySelector("textarea")
// the value of textarea
let value = textarea.value
// split the string from line breaks, so you have arrays of strings seperated from line breaks
let keys = value.split("\n")
// create an object to store the value on
let obj = {}
keys.forEach((val,index) => { // foreach the array
  let splitString = val.split(" ") // split the "Amy apples" into [Amy,apples]
  splitString[1] ? obj[splitString[0]] = splitString[1] : ""
})
//return and log them
console.log(obj)
```

```html
<textarea>
Amy apples
Betty oranges
Cathy watermelon
Daisy bananas
Edward pears
Fiona grapes
</textarea>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```js
function convert() {
  let r= inputText.value.replace(/(\w+) (\w+)/g,'  "$1" : "$2",');
         
  outputText.value =  `{\n${r.slice(0, -1)}\n}`
}
```

```html
<button onclick="convert()">Convert to JSON</button><br>
<textarea id="inputText" rows="10" cols="30">
Amy apples
Betty oranges
Cathy watermelon
Daisy bananas
Edward pears
Fiona grapes</textarea>
<textarea id="outputText" rows="10" cols="30" readonly></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you, just tried this solution and it also worked.